# Excel macro to list files, values in cell A1 and going down

Tags: excel, vba, list, file

Got the code below, but instead of putting the first value in cell A1 it always starts from A3. How to correct this?

```
Sub list_files()
    Dim objFSO As Object
    Dim objFolder As Object
    Dim objFile As Object

    Range("A1", Columns("A").End(xlDown)).Clear
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("C:\files\")
    ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Select
    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
    ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1, 1).Value = objFile.Name
    Next
    Set objFolder = Nothing
    Set objFile = Nothing
    Set objFSO = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `UsedRange` in that way. Instead just increment a variable as below

```
Sub list_files()
    Dim objFSO As Object
    Dim objFolder As Object
    Dim objFile As Object
    Dim rowNumber as long

    rowNumber = 1

    Range("A1", Columns("A").End(xlDown)).Clear
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("C:\files\")

    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files

        ActiveSheet.Cells(rowNumber, 1).Value = objFile.Name
        rowNumber = rowNumber + 1

    Next
    Set objFolder = Nothing
    Set objFile = Nothing
    Set objFSO = Nothing
End Sub
```